# Swapping smallest and largest values in array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I have to input a list of numbers stored in an array, specify how many int values that are to be stored in the array, and print out the original array plus the list of integers with the maximum and minimum values swapped.

**I am not allowed to use library other than java.util.Scanner**

So, if I input {1 2 3 4 5 6 7}, I'm supposed to get {7 2 3 4 5 6 1}.
Everything in my code works except the swapping part, but I've managed to find the maximum and minimum values, I just don't know how to deal with them. Here's what I got:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter array size (minimum size 7)? ");
        int size = in.nextInt();
        int [] array = new int [size];
        System.out.print("Enter " + size + " distinct integer values to store in the array: ");
        
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Original array:");
        
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Array after swapping the smallest and largest:");
        
        int large = array[0];
        int small = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (array[i] > large) {
                large = array[i];
            }
        }
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (array[i] < small) {
                small = array[i];
            }
        }
        
        int temp = small;
        large = large;
        large = temp;
        
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
    
        
    }
```

Comment: Your issue is `int big = 0;` and this loop `for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {` you never actually change the value of `big` anywhere, so it just stays at `0` so when you swap [0] for [0] using `temp` it remains as 1. Rethink that loop, and assign `big` correctly any you will solve your issue.

Comment: @sorifiend Okay I fixed the part where I find the smallest and largest values. The "big" part was a mistake I think it should work now, but it still prints the same array. Thoughts?

Comment: The answer from Bohemian below will solve your issues, specifically `array[small] = i` should change to `small = i` as well as your other change where `array[big] = i` should change to `big = i`

Comment: After the array values have been entered by User: `Arrays.sort(array); int tmp = array[array.length - 1]; array[array.length - 1] = array[0]; array[0] = tmp;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your *main* bug is here:

```
int small = 0;
```

should be

```
int small = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

But that alone won't fix your program. You also need to fix these:

- `for (i = 1; i < size; i++)` should loop from `0`, not `1`.
- `if (array[small] < array[i])` should be `if (array[small] > array[i])`
- `if (array[big] > array[i])` should be `if (array[big] < array[i])`
- `array[small] = i` should be `small = i`
- `array[big] = i` should be `big = i`

---

I recommend replacing your code altogether with:

```
int small = Arrays.stream(array).min().getAsInt();
int big = Arrays.stream(array).max().getAsInt();
```

Comment: The thing here is, I'm not allowed to use any other library than java.util.Scanner. I did try to fix my code to find the largest and smallest values though. Thoughts?

Comment: @Dandouni if you apply the changes I have detailed, it should work. The fact that most of your code has bugs tells me you are not debugging your code. One of the best skills you can learn is how to do that. I recommend you use your IDE's debugger and step through your code to find your bugs - you would be amazed at how fast you will find and fix problems all by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void swapMinMax(int arr[]){
        int minIdx = 0, maxIdx = 0, min = arr[0], max = arr[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(min < arr[i]){
                min = arr[i];
                maxIdx = i;
            }else if(max > arr[i]){
                max = arr[i];
                minIdx = i;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(i == minIdx){
                arr[i] = min;
            }else if(i == maxIdx){
                arr[i] = max;
            }
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ln = scn.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int [ln];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = scn.nextInt();
        }
        swapMinMax(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).